# Mysql search for a string in an Array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Data stored in the database as below where category is column name and comma separated strings are values.

```
category = 'cat,cat1,cat2,cat3,cat33,cat4';
```

I'm trying to search with a category from the list:

```
$query= mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table where
INSTR(category,'cat3') > 1 ");
```

But this doesn't work because the result includes cat3 and cat33.

Any thoughts on how I can do this search, please?

Thanks!

Comment: "Data stored in the database as below where category is column name and comma separated strings are values"—this is a sure sign that you've got a data modeling problem. Multiple values shouldn't be crammed into a single field in your database.

Comment: Someone may suggest using FIND_IN_SET, but the best answer is normalization.

Comment: If you don't yet have the select working for this, I'm gonna presume that means it's not live, otherwise it wouldn't be doing anything. Honestly, extending the comments above, you should take this time while it's not live to add a new table called (eg) `categories` and have each category as a separate row with data in other columns relevant to each cat

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use FIND_IN_SET function :

```
SELECT * FROM table where FIND_IN_SET('cat3', category) > 0
```

But you *should* normalize your data by creating **category** table and relate to your table's primary key

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM table where category LIKE '%cat3,%'";
"SELECT * FROM table where category LIKE '%cat33,%'";
```

if you don't want to add comma to the end of each category name, then 
`"SELECT * FROM table where category LIKE '%cat3,%' OR category LIKE '%cat3'";`

Comment: This will miss the last value in the list.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM table where category LIKE '%cat3,%' OR category LIKE '%cat3'";

Comment: This will also match a category called "somecat3". If you're going to do it the wrong way and not normalize your tables, you could instead use a regular expression: `SELECT * FROM table where category REGEXP '(^|,)cat3(,|$)'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can "solve" this using the query below. BUT I HARDLY RECCOMEND you to normalize your database and use this only if you REALLY NEED

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fild LIKE '%,camp3,%' OR fild LIKE 'camp3' OR field LIKE '%,camp3'
```